# How do I get the full version as a string after packageVersion?

Tags: r

```
 > packageVersion("stats")
 [1] ‘3.5.3’
```

the returned entity is not a string. it's an S3 class of type package_version

```
 > class(packageVersion("stats"))
 [1] "package_version" "numeric_version"
```

This entity has no attributes, no names, nothing.

```
> attributes(packageVersion("stats"))
$class
[1] "package_version" "numeric_version"

> names(packageVersion("stats"))
NULL
```

But somehow this works

```
> packageVersion("stats")$major
[1] 3
```

There's also minor and patch. Question is, how do I get the full version as a string? Corollary question, why don't major, minor and patch show up when I ask for the names, and how can I see the full list of names supported by this entity?

Answer (score 5):

To answer your first question: You can do `as.character(packageVersion(x))`.

The second question is trickier: The S3 class defines its own `$` operator. I have no idea *why*, but here we are.

```
〉`$.package_version`
function (x, name)
{
    name <- pmatch(name, c("major", "minor", "patchlevel"))
    x <- unclass(x)
    switch(name, major = vapply(x, "[", 0L, 1L), minor = vapply(x,
        "[", 0L, 2L), patchlevel = vapply(x, "[", 0L, 3L))
}
<bytecode: 0x7fe3aa8fd000>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

There may be a good reason for this (maybe *lots* of package version numbers are generated and cached, and the extra space savings are relevant) but, honestly, it feels overly clever for no good reason. The code is also fairly convoluted — the same thing could be written a lot simpler.

In particular, the use of `switch` is unnecessary and misleading, and only happens to work because of a lucky coincidence, because `name` *is not a name*, it’s an *integer* (`pmatch` returns the *index* of a partially matching entry). And of course there’s absolutely no reason to repeat all that `vapply` code. So the following does the same, just clearer:

```
`$.package_version` = function (x, name) {
    index = pmatch(name, c("major", "minor", "patchlevel"))
    vapply(unclass(x), `[`, integer(1L), index)
}
```